# Button vanishing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, referenceerror

I am having a problem with putting a button in the following code.
This a `Javascript` program and I get an error message in the console saying:

```
ReferenceError: myClickFunc is not defined
```

while this function is in front of my eyes. Below is the relevant code.

I made a similar post recently without getting an answer, but I got some tips and did some more research in order to solve the problem. Here is the current situation I am in.

The button in the following code before the line:

```
dbRef.on("value", function(snapshot)
```

works as it should but disappears very soon. The other buttons (inside the loop) produce the error message mentioned above. One more thing I noticed is that the page never seems to end loading.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Web application</title>
</head>

<body>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase.js"></script>

<script>

function someCallingFunc(timeRef,work)
{/* Beginning of someCallingFunc */
var workRef = timeRef.child(work)

workRef.on("value", function(workSnapshot) {
    var rcdData = workSnapshot.val();
    document.write("English name: " + rcdData["engName"] + "<br/>\n");
    document.write("<input type='Submit' value='Edit' onClick='myClickFunc()'><br/>\n");
});

}/* End of someCallingFunc */


function myClickFunc()
{/* Beginning of myClickFunc */
window.open("http://www.google.com");
}/* End of myClickFunc */


var config = {
  apiKey: ".........",
  authDomain: "..........firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "..........firebaseio.com",
  projectId: ".........",
  storageBucket: "..........appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "........."
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('DataList');

// This button works but only appears for half a second, then disappears.
document.write("<button onClick='myClickFunc()'>EDIT</button><br/>\n");

dbRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {

for (number in snapshot.val()) {
    document.write("Year " + number + " :<br/>\n");
    var numberRef = dbRef.child(number)
    numberRef.on("value", function(numberSnapshot) {
      for (work in numberSnapshot.val()) {
        someCallingFunc(numberRef,work);
        document.write("<br/>\n");
      }
    });
}});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to change the location of the myClickFunc() in various ways but with no success.

Not being very experienced in JS, I must be doing some beginner mistake. But where is that mistake?

Comment: Your're using `document.write` in an event handler. This event handler is invoked after the page has loaded and `document` has been closed. Because of this, calling `document.write` at this point will overwrite the preexisting content instead of appending to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/write) in the event handler (`dbRef.on("value", ...`). So you're calling it asynchronously, which means the document is closed at this point. Therefore `document.write` will implicitly call [`document.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open), which clears the current page, removing everything that was there (in particular your button).

Instead of using `document.write` to add content to the document, use DOM manipulation. For example, to append a new paragraph to the page, you can do this:

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML = "Hello <b>world!</b>";
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Look at the first note: "...calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open, which will clear the document."

Your event handler is invoked some time after the page has loaded, meaning `document` has been closed.

Instead of using `document.write`, you should directly manipulate the DOM by creating your elements with `document.createElement()` and adding them with `.appendChild()`.
While it works to add your button with `document.write` since it's done while the page is loading and `document` is still open, it's generally speaking a good idea to avoid `document.write` so you should consider adding that with DOM manipulation as well.